# How to use str.isalpha()?

Tags: python, while-loop, isalpha

[image: This is what i have tried.]

I insert 'Sharon' as my input but it still keeps printing "Not in alphabets". What should I do to `print("In alphabets")` while my input is in alphabets?

Comment: Given that `isalpha` exists on a *string* and returns a *boolean*, under what circumstances do you think `name == name.isalpha()` could ever be true?

Comment: Please add code directly to the question using triple backticks, and not as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the statement of the while loop is satisfied, the code in the while loop keeps running.

With your code is like you are saying to the computer: 
While the name variable value is not equal to the Boolean value True, if name is composed of alphabet elements, or is not equal to the Boolean value False, if name is not composed of alphabet elements, keep printing "Not in alphabets".

As you can understand, a strings variable value can never be equal to a Boolean value, thus the while loop never ends.

You need an `if else`, not a `while`.

```
if name.isalpha() != False:
    print( "Not in alphabets")
else:
    print("In alphabets")
```

**ALSO: Post written code inside ` and not as image!**

Comment: The explanantion isn't fully correct. The original code doesn't compare whether the "name is not composed of alphabet elements". It checks if `name` is not equal to the return value of `isalpha` and this comparison will always be `True`. A string will never be the same as the boolean values `True` or `False`.

Comment: @Mattthias is right. I am editing my answer! Sorry about about the confusion

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to do this? I

```py
name = input("Enter your name")

if name.isalpha():
    print("All chars are alphabetic")
else:
    print("Not all charts are alphabetic")
```